# How to implement "remember me" feature in feathers.js and JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, feathersjs

Feathers use JSON web token for auth. How can I conditionally set token's `expiresIn` property depends on "remember me" was checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to not remember a JWT is not to store it on the client side. If you are using the Feathers client with authentication the token is stored in localStorage as `feathers-jwt`. You can "unremember" it for the next browser session by calling

```
localStorage.removeItem('feathers-jwt')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what about server side? Could it be done with expiresIn token property. I just don't understand where I can set it except auth configuration for whole app but it's not the way.

Comment: The server does not store JWT's so the only way to know if a token is expired is by implementing your own token blacklisting mechanism. With feathers-authentication 1.0 you can set a dynamic expiration time if you wish so but without a blacklist it is not possible to invalidate a token before its expiration.

Comment: @daff And if that code can't run before the user leaves? E.g. sudden browser crash - one solution could be if we could use SessionStorage for not remembering and LocalStorage for remembering. I suppose that can be implemented by using redux to store the remember state and accessing that from a custom storage that you hand to `feathers.authentication` configuration. (remember state would have to persist between browser refreshes) That's what I'm going to look at implementing, not sure how feathers-auth can help the if you don't have a global state store like redux. Some kind of hook.

Answer (score 4):

***Updated thoughts***: this method is a hack (potentially with security implications) - what I think should happen is if you click remember me, you should be issued a refresh token which should be used to issue a new token automatically should it expire or not exist. I'd love to hear what suggestions the feathers devs have - I'm looking into this and will report back if I find a better solution

What might happen with a cookie-based solution is if a user sets remember me, they are issued with a token with an expiry date, otherwise they are issued a session cookie which is removed once the browser session ends (browser is closed). When using a JSON Web Token(JWT) with `feathers.authentication` (< 1.x ??) we are storing a JSON Web Token (JWT) in a storage provider such as `localStorage`. If you want your login token to disappear after the browser closes you should use `sessionStorage`.

My current solution is to use both, depending on my form value when I logged in. In the case the user chooses 'remember me' I'll call `storage.setShouldPersist(true)` (likewise `storage.setShouldPesist(false)` if remember me is not checked) which will place a flag in localstorage saying that we are in "localStorage" mode. I pass an object which duck types Storage (`getItem`, `setItem` etc.) to `feather.authentication` which checks if my rememberme key is present. If so, it uses `localStorage` otherwise it uses `sessionsStorage`.

Here is the code:

```
// localOrSessionStore.js
const { localStorage, sessionStorage } = global;

export default function localOrSessionStore({ key }) {
  let shouldPersist = localStorage.getItem(key) === 't';

  return {
    setShouldPersist(persist) {
      shouldPersist = !!persist;
      if (persist) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, 't');
      }  else {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
      }
    },

    getItem(name) {
      if (shouldPersist) {
        return localStorage.getItem(name);
      }

      return sessionStorage.getItem(name);
    },

    setItem(name, value) {
      if (shouldPersist) {
        return localStorage.setItem(name, value);
      }

      return sessionStorage.setItem(name, value);
    },

    removeItem(name) {
      if (shouldPersist) {
        return localStorage.removeItem(name);
      }

      return sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
    },
  };
}
```

Then usage:

```
# feathers.js - where I set up feathers for my app
export const storage = localOrSessionStore({ key: 'myapprmbr' });
export default feathers()
  .configure(rest('/api').fetch(fetch))
  .configure(feathers.hooks())
  .configure(feathers.authentication({
    storage, // Passed into feathers-auth here
    tokenKey: 'myappjwt',
  });
```

The new `feathers-authetication@>=1.x` and `feathers-authetication-client` packages have some changes which I'm not yet familiar with, which may better enable remember me functionality.